# Format a number with a specific mask

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, format, string.format

I need a help (c#) for the following problem:

- I have this value as int : 11110006;
- I want to show this value with this specific mask: 0:0.0.0.00.00-0
- the result must be 1.1.1.10.00-6

In my view, I already tried:

```
<td style="text-align:left"><%= String.Format("{0:0.0.0.00.00-0}", cosif.IDCONTACOSIF) %></td>
```

and

```
<td style="text-align:left"><%= String.Format("{#:#.#.#.##.##-#}", cosif.IDCONTACOSIF) %></td>
```

Or even

```
<td style="text-align:left"><%= cosif.IDCONTACOSIF.ToString("My Mask ###") %></td>
```

Nothing is working... sometimes, it shows like a currency number, but I don't want to
show it like a currency, because it isn't a currency value.

Any idea?

Best regards..

Comment: convert the int to a string, then feed the various "digits" to a string mask.

Comment: feed with various "digits"? Sorry @MarcB, but I didn't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a format string in the form of `0:0.0.0.00.00-0` try using single quotes or double quotes to encase the periods in the format string. As it is being interpreted as a decimal separator, as in `0.45678 ("0.00", en-US) -> 0.46`

So for example try: `("#':'#'.'#'.'#'.'##'.'##'-'#")`

[this text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)  shows the place holders in the format string you should use.